# Knex alter table not adding column

Tags: node.js, nodes, knex.js

I am writing the migration and the code looks like this

```
exports.up = async (knex) => {
    knex.schema.alterTable('history', function(table) {
        table.string('someCheck', 20).nullable().defaultTo(null);
    });
};
```

Once I run `node -r dotenv/config ./node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js migrate:up` it says that is successful.

```
Using environment: development
Batch 3 ran the following migrations:
2021051304151_add-check-field.js
```

And once I check the `history` table there are no new fields.

Answer (score 2):

```
exports.up = async (knex) => {
    return knex.schema.alterTable('history', function(table) {
        table.string('someCheck', 20).nullable().defaultTo(null);
    });
};
```

or

```
exports.up = async (knex) => {
    await knex.schema.alterTable('history', function(table) {
        table.string('someCheck', 20).nullable().defaultTo(null);
    });
};
```

Will work. Now query builder is not executed.